# Dymola: why choosing which integration method

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

Simulating models with dymola, I get different results depending on the chosen integration method. So my question is: why choose which method?

Answer (score 6):

Ideally the choice of method should be based on which one most quickly gives a result close enough to the exact result.

But we don't know the exact result, and in this case at least some of the solvers (likely all) don't generate a result close enough to it.

**One possibility is to first try to simulate with a lot stricter tolerance - e.g. 1e-9.** (Note: for the fixed step-size solvers, Euler and Rkfix* it would be smaller step-size, but don't start using them.)

Hopefully the difference between the solvers will decrease and the different solvers give more similar results (which should be close to the exact one).

You can then always use this stricter tolerance. Or in case one solver already gave the same result with less strict tolerance - then you can use that one at less strict tolerance; but you also have to make a trade-off between the accuracy and simulation-time.

Sometimes this does not happen and even the same solver generate different results for different tolerances; without converging to a true solution.
(Assumedly the solution are close together at the start but then quickly diverge.)
It is likely that the model is chaotic in that case. That is a bit more complicated to handle and there are several options:

- It could be due to a modeling error that can be corrected
- It could be that the model is correct, but the system could be changed to become smoother
- It could be that the important outputs converge regardless of differences in other variables

It could also be some other error (including problems during initialization), but that requires a more complete example to investigate.

Answer (score 2):

Choose the solver that matches best the exact solution.

Maybe Robert Piché's [work](http://virtual.cvut.cz/odl/partners/tut/unit2/mklunit2.html) on numerical solvers gives some more clues.